# Cannot read property 'markdownRemark' of undefined (GatsbyJS)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

hope you all safe out there!. I've problem while deploying production GatsbyJS on Netlify and it goes to Cannot read property 'markdownRemark' of undefined, then production is failed.

[image: Error on Netlify]

The whole branch actually normal while develop and building production on local with zero error, run smoothly and that's why we merging to master then recheck for build production on final branch, and again no problem with that. The question is, why?

Here's the code :

```
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { Disqus, CommentCount } from "gatsby-plugin-disqus"

import "../styles/index.scss"
import { slugify } from "../utils/utilityFunction"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar"
import SEO from "../components/Seo"

export default function blogTemplate({ data, pageContext }) {
  const post = data.markdownRemark
  const { title, author, date, link, path, tags } = post.frontmatter
  const { shortenedLink } = pageContext

  // pas production mode, kalau disqusconfig nya sesuain sama production nya yaa~
  const disqusConfig = {
    // url: `himitsu.dev${path}`,
    title: title,
    identifier: path.split("/").slice(-1)[0],
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title={title} keyword={("Idols", "Music" + title)} />
      <div className="row mt-3">
        <div className="col-md-8">
          <div className="content-bar">
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>
              Posted by {author} on {date} |{" "}
              <CommentCount config={disqusConfig} />
            </p>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
            {link.length > 0 && (
              <div className="card mx-auto mt-4" style={{ maxWidth: "600px" }}>
                <div className="card-header text-center">
                  Downloadable Content
                </div>
                {link.map((i, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={i.label} className="list-group-item text-center">
                      <span className="font-weight-bold mr-2">[{i.label}]</span>
                      <a
                        href={shortenedLink[index]}
                        target="_blank"
                        rel="noreferrer"
                      >
                        {shortenedLink[index]}
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  )
                })}
              </div>
            )}
            <div style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}>
              Tags :{" "}
              {tags.map(tag => (
                <div className="mr-1 d-inline-flex" key={tag}>
                  <Link to={`/tag/${slugify(tag)}`}>
                    <span className="badge badge-secondary text-uppercase">
                      {tag}
                    </span>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div style={{ marginTop: "3rem" }}>
              <Disqus config={disqusConfig} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const blogQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPerPosts($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
      frontmatter {
        author
        date
        title
        path
        tags
        link {
          label
          url
        }
      }
      html
    }
  }
`
```

Sorry for my poor english..

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you have no markdown files stored on your master branch (that is deployed to Netlify)? If you are fetching the markdown files from somewhere, check if the data fetching worked (maybe a missing environment variable on Netlify?)

Comment: yes, seems be like that. But netlify auto publishing was deploying my production branch, and successfully deployed, then i just replace some blog content like blog description just to make sure deployment is really successful, and pushing into production branch. Error again then, very confused. Here's the screenshot https://imgur.com/0JZbqfj and https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: Double check your environment variables on netlify vs local environment. If you confirmed they are valid, I would `rm -rf node_modules .cache` locally to clear the gatsby cache. Run `npm i` and make sure that all content (e.g. your blob posts) are exactly the same on prod and local. Try to debug locally and find the error by building locally.